# How are system calls interpreted in x86 assembly linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am confused towards why/how a value gets printed in x86 assembly in a Linux environment.

For example if I wish to print a value I would do this:

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, msg
mov edx msgLength
int 80h
```

Now I understand the numerical value 4 will make the system call to sys_write after the interrupt. But my question is, what is the significance of the 4? Is it loading the address of the decimal value 4 into `eax`? Or is it loading the value 4 into the `eax` register?

I am confused after reading I can transfer the value at an address to a register using the following instruction:

```
mov eax, [msg]
```

`eax` will now contain the bytes at the address of `msg`, but I would guess this format is not acceptable:

```
mov eax, [4]
```

So what is really happening when I move 4 into eax to print something?

Comment: Note the syntax varies with the assembler. With Microsoft (and probably Intel) assember, | mov ecx, msg | is going to load the first 4 bytes at msg into ecx. To get the address | mov ecx, offset msg | is used with these assemblers. Brackets [] are only used for register indirect operands, such as | mov ecx, [ebx] | .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply the value (number) 4 is loaded into `eax`, no magic there. The operating system will look at the value in `eax` to figure out what function you want. System call number is a code that identifies the various available kernel functions you can use.

Answer (score 2):

Linux kernel maintains all the system call routines as an array of function pointers (can be called as sys_call table) and the value in the eax gives the index to that array (which system call to choose) by the kernel. Other registers like ebx, ecx, edx contains the appropriate parameters for that system call routine. 
And the int 80h is for software interrupt to the cpu from user mode to kernel mode because actual system call routine is kernel space function.

Comment: The system call dispatch table is indeed called `sys_call_table` and the system call number ("_a unique integer (i.e., whole number), from one to around 256_") stored in the `eax` register is used as index as can be seen here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.18/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L427